# From sum to quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have here a short question about how I can formulate the following sum in quadratic form:

Let $x^i \in R^m$ and $x=[x^1 , ... , x^N]^T$ be the stacked vector of the $x^i$. ($i$ is here an index, not a power).

$$\sum_i^N \left(\sum_j^N x^j\right)^T x^i  = x^T H x + f x$$

Where I am looking for $H$ and $f$. I need them to solve an optimization problem.

Comment: Well, from the rules of transpose follows, that the transpose of a sum is each component transposed itself. It's just more convenient to write the transpose operator outside of the sum.